# Pip install states module is already downloaded but I can't use it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pip, mu

I am using a python editor called 'Mu' and want to download a module called 'pyperclip' with pip install. I am operating on Windows 10 and typed

```
pip install --user pyperclip
```

on the command prompt. The first time I did this, the prompt said it was downloaded. However, when I try to import the module on 'Mu', it states

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'

When I try to pip install the module again it gives me:

> Requirement already satisfied: pyperclip in c:\users{my name}\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (1.8.1)

I think the issue is that the module is not downloaded in a place that 'Mu' can access. How can I pip install a module into this editor?

Comment: I'd guess your editor is using Python 2 instead of Python 3 to interpret your code. Check what version of python it's using. For example in VS code you can change the directory where it searches to find an interpreter. Check whether there's a similar option for Mu.

Comment: If you are on a PC, make sure that you checked off "Add to PATH" when you install python. Otherwise, your libraries/frameworks won't be included in the path for your program and can't be imported